# C# - I'd like to create folders specified in textbox by the user. How is it possible to make sure that comma will work as the seperator?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(foldercreationPATH.Text + "\\Tosystem\\" + customersBOX.Text);
```

Now, if user specifies folder(names) to be created separated by comma, how can I do it?

E.g. if textbox contains "customer1, customer2", then I would like to create separate folders for these.

Comment: Use string.Split then loop on the resulting array or list and create your folders one by one

Comment: string[] items=customersBOX.Text.Split(',',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) then process items[i]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would take the string inside the textbox and use the
    .split()
method to create an array which you can loop through using a
    foreach
loop. I also invoked the
    .Trim()
method to remove any trailing white space.

```
string[] strArr = customersBOX.Text.Split(',');
foreach (string item in strArr)
{
    item.Trim();
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(foldercreationPATH.Text + "\\Tosystem\\" + item);            
}
```

Comment: There are more validation options recommended as it is a user input field. It's worth looking at sm.abdullah's answer as he removes empty entries however it all depends on how you plan to use this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
  var dirs = customersBOX.Text.Split(",".ToArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (var dir in dirs)
                {
                    var finalPath = Path.Combine(foldercreationPATH.Text, "Tosystem", dir);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(finalPath);
                }
```